# Tool for writing zeroes to HDD that ignores write errors

Tags: hard-drive

I have a HDD which I need to overwrite completely at least once (zeros or random i dont care). While there are a lot of free windows tools for that, the ones I tried stop or even crash when encountering write errors.

The disk is quite large (6TB) and the errors appear in the second half, so it always takes about two days to see if a tool can handle the errors.
Does anybody know of a **open-source or free windows tool** that explicitly offers the option of ignoring write errors?

Thanks!

Comment: I intentionally did not write which tools I tried, because I do not want to start a good tool/bad tool discussion. I do however (as stated) need a tool that has a specific feature. 
The tools I tried did not have that feature, so mentioning them would be pointless.

Comment: There is no opinion to be had about whether a software has a feature or not. Either it is there or not.

Comment: @Moss It is unlikely that a good/bad software discussion would start here. If you had said that you tried the manufacturer's disk diagnostic wipe utility, then we would not suggest trying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the free `dd` utility present in pretty much every Unixoid system (eg. All Macs, Unixes, Linuxes, ...).

I'd suggest booting a live image like Ubuntu and procceed like this:

- Then enter a terminal and obtain root privileges if you're not already root: `sudo -s`.
- List all devices connected to the system using `lsblk`. The output will show you a list with the corresponding sizes. Find the Disk you're looking for (usually `sd<letter>`).
- Confirm that you selected the correct device! Once started you are not getting your data back!
- Now we will copy zeroes from /dev/zero to that device using `dd` like this:
  `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/<your drive name, could be "sda", and without quotes> bs=64k conv=noerror`. Note that dd will not show you any data about what it's doing. To get more information you can try adding a last argument to see it's progress: `status=progress`, but it isn't supported on all systems.

Example command: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=64k conv=noerror status=progress`

Warning: `dd` is a very powerful utility and totally capable of destroying what you don't want to be destroyed if you, for example, just copy the command above!

**Edit:** If dd should still stop when encountering write errors like @oldmud0 pointed out take a look at this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229356

**Edit 2:** Since the drive is broken you could also just physically destroy it.

**Edit 3:** Apparently using `conv=notrunc` did the trick for some users, i'd suggest trying that.

Comment: `dd` does not ignore write errors. See this question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229354/how-to-ignore-write-errors-while-zeroing-a-disk