# Windows 10 install error: "Windows cannot continue due to a corrupted installation file"

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation, windows-installer

I've been trying to install Windows 10 for quite some time now, but every time I do I get error:

```
Windows cannot continue due to a corrupted installation file.
Contact the vendor of your Windows installation disc or your system administrator for assistance.
```

- I  have tried formatting the hard drive, but still nothing works, and I saw something about zeroing the first MB of the hard drive, but I don't understand
- I have tried multiple ISO files, but it keeps giving the same error

How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: I have tried multiple iso files, but it keeps giving the same error.

Comment: Then try replacing the  hard drive

Comment: I don't know if it's the hard drive with the problem, but I just want to know how I can fix it.

Comment: Did you download the ISO directly from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO)? If not, doing so should fix the issue, but if that's where the ISO came from, re-download it, as it's possible the download was corrupted _(Microsoft lists the hash for the ISO, but I'm not sure where, as comparing the hash is the best way to determine if the ISO is corrupted)_, however it's unlikely it's an issue with the hard drive _(a drive issue wouldn't result in this error, however it could be an issue with the USB drive - try a different USB drive for the install USB)_

Comment: "zeroing the first MB" is using a partitioning program of your choice to write 0's over the 1st megabyte of the HDD.  [I suggest you do that](https://superuser.com/questions/1093474/tool-for-writing-zeroes-to-hdd-that-ignores-write-errors)

Comment: @JW0914 I've been using the same iso file on different computers now and I've never encountered such an error. I've also tried to use 3 different USB drives now, but still.

Comment: @Ramhound Do you know how that solves the problem?

Comment: @DreadDoc - Have you tried it?

Comment: @DreadDoc Review Windows setup logs _(within a hidden folder in the root of `C:` or within `C:\Windows`)_  would be recommended to review. Rule out bad blocks from the install GUI: `Shift`+`F10` → `chkdsk <letter>: /OfflineScanAndFix`, then run a S.M.A.R.T test & review the S.M.A.R.T data on a Linux LiveUSB; however, zeroing the first MB likely wouldn't resolve the error since the system partition is never the first partition, Boot [configured before setup reboot] or WinRE is. If S.M.A.R.T doesn't show an issue & wiping the partition table doesn't solve it, it's likely not the HDD.

Comment: I don't know why, but I downloaded the iso file from Microsoft and it got me past the error. Now I have another error  ``` The operating system couldn't be loaded because the system registry file is missing or contains errors```

Comment: @DreadDoc The only way the system Registry hives [located in `%WinDir%\System32\config`] could be corrupted on a new install is due to malware or a failing drive, which is why I recommended running a S.M.A.R.T test from a Linux Live USB _(see [this](https://superuser.com/a/1466640/529800) answer)_.

Comment: @JW0914 Thank you! The Problem was with the drive.